# split column into multiple columns pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a json file that I splited into 2 column using pandas, and it looks like this :

```
 URL        report
0  121      [{'detected': True, 'name': 'Alfa', 'version' : '21.04'},{'detected': True, 'name': 'Alfa1'} ...
1  104      [{'detected': True, 'name': 'Beta', 'version' : '25.04.01'},{'detected': True, 'name': 'Beta3'}...
2  112      [{'detected': False, 'name': 'Alfa', 'version' : '21.04'},{'detected': True, 'name': 'Beta'}...
```

I want to make it look like this, removing the 'version':

```
URL        report_1                             report_2                              report_3
0  121     {'detected': True, 'name': 'Alfa'}   {'detected': True, 'name': 'Alfa1'} ...
1  104     {'detected': True, 'name': 'Beta'}   {'detected': True, 'name': 'Beta3'}...
2  112     {'detected': False, 'name': 'Alfa'}  {'detected': True, 'name': 'Beta'}...
```

The number of reports is not the same for every URL. Please if anyone could help me as I am struggling to find out how to split them. Many thanks in advance!

I honestly do not know what to try as I cannot seem to find a code that would work.

Comment: `df.explode('report')` then pivot by the two columns Q/A 10 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe).

Answer (score 0):

As you have a Series of lists, you need to loop to remove the keys:

```
drop = {'version'}

df['report'] = [[{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in drop}
                 for d in l] for l in df['report']]
```

Output:

```
   URL                                                                     report
0  121  [{'detected': True, 'name': 'Alfa'}, {'detected': True, 'name': 'Alfa1'}]
1  104  [{'detected': True, 'name': 'Beta'}, {'detected': True, 'name': 'Beta3'}]
2  112  [{'detected': False, 'name': 'Alfa'}, {'detected': True, 'name': 'Beta'}]
```

Then for the final output, `pivot`:

```
(df.explode('report').assign(col=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1))
   .pivot(index='URL', columns='col', values='report')
   .add_prefix('report_').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
   URL                             report_1                             report_2
0  104   {'detected': True, 'name': 'Beta'}  {'detected': True, 'name': 'Beta3'}
1  112  {'detected': False, 'name': 'Alfa'}   {'detected': True, 'name': 'Beta'}
2  121   {'detected': True, 'name': 'Alfa'}  {'detected': True, 'name': 'Alfa1'}
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'URL': [121, 104, 112],
                   'report': [[{'detected': True, 'name': 'Alfa', 'version' : '21.04'},
                               {'detected': True, 'name': 'Alfa1'}],
                              [{'detected': True, 'name': 'Beta', 'version' : '25.04.01'},
                               {'detected': True, 'name': 'Beta3'}],
                              [{'detected': False, 'name': 'Alfa', 'version' : '21.04'},
                               {'detected': True, 'name': 'Beta'}]],
                  })
```